# How to prevent Puppet's file_line resource from always triggering an event?

Tags: puppet

I use the *file_line* resource from puppetlabs/stdlib to add lines to a file with Puppet. I would like to trigger a service reload when the *file_line* actually changes the file. Here is what I've tried:

**First try**

```
service { 'test-service':
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => true
}
file_line { 'test':
  path   => '/file'
  line   => 'test parameter'
  notify => Service['test-service']
}
```

**Second try**

```
service { 'test-service':
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => true
}
file_line { 'test':
  path   => '/file'
  line   => 'test parameter'
}~>Service['test-service']
```

Or similar with `File_line['test']~>Service['test-service']` on the header.

**Third try**

```
file { '/file':
  path   => '/file',
  notify => Service['test-service']
}
service { 'test-service':
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => true
}
file_line { 'test':
  path   => '/file'
  line   => 'test parameter'
}
```

**Fourth try**

```
service { 'test-service':
  ensure    => 'running',
  enable    => true,
  subscribe => File_line['test']
}
file_line { 'test':
  path   => '/file'
  line   => 'test parameter'
}
```

In each case, *file_line* always trigger the service reload, even when nothing has changed in the file. It seems *file_line* is first removing all lines, and then re-adding them. Playing with the *match* option didn't change this behaviour.

How to make it trigger the service reload **only** if the file has changed?

Edit: here is the output of `puppet agent --test`:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Profile::testprofile/File_line[test]/ensure: created
Info: /Stage[main]/Profile::testprofile/File_line[test]: Scheduling refresh of Service[test-service]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Profile::testprofile/Service[test-service]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `puppet agent -t` to your question?

Comment: I added the output, but I figured it seems to be a bug, I'll reply my own question. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured this had to do with the content I was writing to the file!
If you try to add carriage returns using *file_line*, it will always trigger a refresh:

```
file_line { 'test':
  path => '/file',
  line => 'first param\nsecond param'
}
```

If I remove the `\n`, the problem disappear. So better call *file_line* twice than once with carriage returns.

Comment: Or you can use the double-quote around the `line` parameter, as double-quotes respect line-breaks within them, and single-quotes do not.